# Translate Navigation Menu & Sidebar Widget Titles

Tags: translation

Is there any plugin to translate navigation menu & sidebar widget titles ?

Comment: Can you give some additional information? are they currently in need of translation to apear normaly?? would the visitors click on something to get to a translated version of the website ??

Comment: I want manual translation. I already have translation contents (wordings). I just want to translate the menu as well as widget titles to different language, with a  switch using drop down menu.

Comment: i see.. well :) as long as it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, I found my answer.

I used `qTranslate` to translate menu wordings as well as widget titles. Free & useful.

Comment: I don't see option for translating sidebar widgets. Is there any hack to do this?

Comment: You can use shorttag of `qTranslate` to translate the wordings.

Comment: Do you mean [:en] and for example [:fr]?

Comment: Yes. There are also other tags available. Read their doc.

Comment: You are right, it's working.