# Multi language site

Tags: plugins, widgets, multi-language, plugin-qtranslate

I found that two most popular plugins for multi language sites are WMPL and qTranslate. First one is commercial, so this is not option, and second doesn't have ability to translate widgets in sidebars, or I don't know how to do it.
Can you suggest me which plugin to use or what trick to do to have multi language widgets?

Comment: If you're using 3rd party plugin it depends how the author has written them. Some are just not written for translation. We've done multi language sites at work by using a multisite install and language subdomains so everything on the site can be translated in the admin.

Answer (score 1):

I have used qTransalte a lot of times... i some cases i have used this kinda of code
for widgets and special elements in the design such as the logo / images

```
$bloginfo = get_bloginfo( 'language' );
if ($bloginfo == 'he-IL') {
   // hebrew sidebar here
} else {
   // English sidebar here
}
```

.
But that just in specific cases... in most cases qTranslate has a ready made solution.

Best of luck.
Sagive

Comment: Where you put this code? My main concern are widgets? Could this technique be applied to widget?

Comment: You can create an additional sidebar just for the desired language and use the condition i gave you to load that specific sidebar if in a specific language.. different titles for it.. - is that clear? i could try to explain better... you know how to create additional sidebars using register sidebar?

Comment: No, I don't know how to create additional sidebar because I am not so experienced wordpress user. But I found solution here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/32489/7800. Anyway your code could help me for other things. Thakns.

Comment: My pleasure mate.. if you need anything else would gladly help